# При перезагрузке блока не срабатывает ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

index.php:

```
<div class="formreload">
        <form action="reg.php" method="post" class="ajax regf">
        <?php
        $sql = mysqli_query ( $link, "SELECT * FROM reg WHERE status='inactive'" );
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
            if (isset($result["login"])) {
                $login = $result["login"]; $type = $result["type"];
                echo "Пользователь под логином <b>$login</b> 
                    пытается зарегистрироваться с правами <b>$type</b> ";
                echo '<input type="text" value="'.$login.'" name="loginn" style="display:none">
                      <input id="getaccess" type="text" name="access" style="display:none">';
            } else echo "Нет аккаунтов для подтверждения";
        ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
        if (isset($result["login"])) echo '<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn regb" id="allow">разрешить</a>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn regb" id="ban">запретить</a>';
    ?>
    <div class="resultat3"></div>
```

reg.php:

```
<?php
$loginn = $_POST["loginn"]; $access = $_POST["access"];
switch ($access) {
    case "allow":
        echo "Запит на підтвердження реєстрації<br>Реєстрація аккаунта<b> ".$loginn."</b> схвалена.";
        mysqli_query( $link, "UPDATE reg SET status='active' WHERE login='$loginn'");
    break;

    case "ban":
        echo "Запит на підтвердження реєстрації<br>Реєстрація аккаунта<b> ".$loginn."</b> не схвалена.";
        mysqli_query( $link, "DELETE FROM reg WHERE login='$loginn'");
    break;
}
?>
```

ajax.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ajax').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var a = $(this).attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(result) {
                     $(".resultat3").html(result); 
            },
        });
    });

    $("#allow").click(function(){
        $("#getaccess").val("allow");
    });

    $("#ban").click(function(){
        $("#getaccess").val("ban");
    });

    $(".regb").click(function(){
        $(".regf").submit();
        $(".formreload").load("index.php .regf");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: То есть, я первый раз нажимаю на кнопку allow или ban и всё срабатывает, <div class="resultat3"></div> обновляется и там появляется новый аккаунт для подтверждения, когда я пытаюсь ещё раз нажать на кнопку, то меня уже перекидывает на прямую в файл reg.php и там выполняется php код.

Answer (score 0):

Уже не нужно) Я решил проблему.  нужно перенести внутрь формы, чтобы в нём был PHP код, и в JS поменять $(".regf").load("index.php .formreload");